Lower increment in filename
I have a folder with different files incremented.
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-001.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-002.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-003.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-004.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-005.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-006.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-007.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-008.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-011.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-012.pdf
[...]
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-002.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-003.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-004.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-005.pdf
[...]
darin_lab_dar04-15-054.pdf

My files starts at 001, I would like them to start at 000:
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-000.pdf 
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-001.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-002.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-003.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-004.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-005.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-006.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-007.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-008.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-011.pdf
[...]
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-149.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-000.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-002.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-003.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-004.pdf
[...]
darin_lab_dar04-15-053.pdf

Is there a way in bash to "decrease" the increment of a bunch of files by one?

There's nothing built in to do this. But it should be straightforward to write a script that does it. Exract the number from the filename, subtract 1 from it, and rename the file with that substitution.

Just make sure you process the files in order. Otherwise you'll rename 003 to 002 before you rename 002, and you'll lose the original 002 file. Luckily, wildcard expansion returns filenames in lexicographic order.

I assume you know how to do arithmetic in bash. If not, you need to learn this, we don't teach the basics here.

if you understand how this answer to your previous question works then you're mostly done: subtract one from last, remove the last test ([[ "${last} != "${last03}" ]]), the echo mv ... should remain the same; if you have problems modifying that answer/code then come back and update the question with your (modified) coding attempt and the (wrong) results generated by said code; as Barmar has pointed out: decrementing the number should not be a problem due to how wildcard expansion works, but if you were to attempt +1 then more care is needed

for a given fixed prefix (eg, kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-) could there be gaps in the numbering? and if there are gaps do you also need to remove the gaps? if you answered 'yes' to either/both of these questions then please update the question with an example gap and an explanation of what to do about the gap

for a given fixed prefix (eg, kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-) if the first number is not 001 (eg, let's say it's 005) then what? decrement by 1 or decrement by whatever it takes to make the first number 000?  if you have to worry about the script being run more than once then you'll need to consider additional coding to skip the decrement if the first number is already 000

@markp-fuso There is no gap in numbering.

@Computable Sorry for that. It is an error. There is no gap.

@markp-fuso In my case, the first number is always 001.

Given this file pattern:
$ tree .
.
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-002.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-003.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-004.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-005.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-054.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-001.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-002.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-003.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-004.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-005.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-006.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-007.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-011.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-012.pdf
└── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf

Here is an GNU awk that does that:
gawk '
    match($0, "(^.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)\\.([^.]+)$", a) {
        new_file=a[1] sprintf("%0*i", length(a[2]), a[2]-1) "." a[3]
        old_file=sprintf("%s%s.%s", a[1],a[2],a[3])
        tab=1
        while (system("test -e " new_file)==0) 
            new_file=a[1] a[2] "_" tab++ "." a[3]

        printf "\"%s\" => \"%s\"\n", old_file, new_file
        s=sprintf("mv \"%s\" \"%s\"", old_file, new_file)
        system(s)
    }
' <(printf "%s\n" *.pdf)

Or in Bash:
#!/bin/bash

fp='(^.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)\.([^.]+)$'

for fn in *.pdf; do
    if [[ $fn =~ $fp ]]; then 
        old_file=$fn
        fp1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fp2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        fp3=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        nn=$(printf "%0*i" ${#fp2} $(( 10#$fp2-1 )) )
        tag=0
        nf="${fp1}${nn}.${fp3}"
        while [ -e "$nf" ]
        do
            tag+=1
            nf="${fp1}${nn}_${tag}.${fp3}"
        done
        echo "$old_file => $nf"
        mv "$old_file" "$nf"
    fi    
done     

Either modifies the file names to be:
tree .
.
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-000.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-002.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-003.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-004.pdf
├── darin_lab_dar04-15-053.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-000.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-001.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-002.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-003.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-004.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-005.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-006.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-008.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
├── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-011.pdf
└── kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-149.pdf


@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub the link you give is for another issue.

@ppr Sorry misreading. But this should be simplier:  (using extglob is lighter than regex): lastbase=;for file in *-[0-9]*.pdf;do basename=${file%-+([0-9]).pdf};[[ $basename != "$lastbase" ]] && cnt=0 lastbase=$basename;printf -v newname '%s-%03d.pdf' "$basename" $((cnt++));[[ $file != "$newname" ]] && mv -i "$file" "$newname";done

This might help with Perl's rename: rename 's/(\d\d\d)/sprintf("%03d",$1-1)/e' *.pdf

Or this, using Perl's rename and ls | sed | sort to ensure increment order: rename 'my $o=$_;s/(.*)-(\d+)(\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})$/$1-000$3/;s/(.*)-(\d+)(\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})$/my $i=$2;$i=0 unless $i;sprintf("%s-%03d%s", $1, $i+1, $3)/eg while $o ne $_  && -f $_;' $(ls -1 *.pdf | sed 'h;s/.*-//;G;s/\n/\t/' | sort -n| sed 's/.*\t//')

Then further rename 's/(.*)-(\d+)(\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})$/sprintf("%s-%03d%s", $1, $2+1, $3)/eg' $(ls -1r *.pdf) if you want number to start at "001".

I love the rename suggestions! I have used it and love Perl type substitutions. The main issue I have with it in cases like this is a new name overrunning an existing name and clobbering that file. Granted, in this case, it works great! But as habit I do check for file collisions and add a second incrementor to avoid data loss.
